# Missing number, treated as zero in longtblr?

Tags: overleaf, tabularray

I tried to reproduce a table I found in `tabularray`, and it did not look like what I expected it to. I use Overleaf.

MWE:

```
    \begin{document}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \usepackage[skip=1ex, 
                font=small,
                labelfont=bf]{caption}
    
    \usepackage{longtable}
    
    \NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue2}
    \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}
    }
    
    %\begin{longtblr}[
    theme = fancy,
    caption = {Comparison between the difference in the computed electrostatic potential contribution ($\Delta \Psi$} and the difference in experimental relative current ($\Delta V_0.5$),
    label = {tblr:deltavalues},
    note{a} = {Both values are in milliVolt.},
    note{$\dag$} = {Both computational and experimental data in free-cAMP state.},
    remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
    ]{
    colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.75\linewidth,
    rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1,
    row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
    row{2-5} = {blue}, row{Z} = {blue7},
    }
    \hline
    Mutations & Computed $\Delta \Psi$ & Experimental $\Delta V_0.5$ \\
    \hline
    D244A & -6.3 & -5.9 \\
    \hline
    D244K & -12.9 & -6.8 \\
    \hline
    E247A & -15 & -13.4 \\
    \hline
    E247R & -34.8 & -5.7 \\
    \hline
    K464A & 7 & 8.9 \\
    \hline
    K464E & 14.4 & 22.8 \\
    \hline
    K472A & 1.5 & 14.7 \\
    \hline
    K472E & 3.6 & 19.6
    \hline
    M155A & 0.4 & 1.9 \\
    \hline
    M155E & 13.4 & 13.7 \\
    \hline
    M155R & -15.3 & -3 \\
    \hline
    Q539A & 0.3 & -1.8 \\
    \hline
    R470E & 16.6 & 0.3 \\
    \end{longtblr}
    
    end{document}
```

error is:

> missing number, treated as zero

Comment: If I add documentclass and edit some mistakes in the code like removing comment before `longtblr`, placing the `\begin{document}` correctly, etc, then I get no error and the output is https://imgur.com/4qc3K8u

Comment: where did you compile?

Comment: Overleaf. By the way, the default tabularray version in Overleaf is often outdated, so I always use the latest version from the [github repo](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/blob/main/tabularray.sty).

Comment: Please give us the first 5 lines of the error.

Comment: @Imran excuse me, i am just getting started with LaTeX, so i am not sure what to do with this repo?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz 

<to be read again> 
                   Z
l.43 \end
         {longtblr}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   Z
l.43 \end
         {longtblr}
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

Comment: @sphero Create a `tabularray.sty` file in your overleaf working directory and paste the code from the link I shared in my last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your code fragment is very badly composed. It contains many errors like loading packages after `begin{document}`, essential part of code commented out, etc.
- Why do you use `longtblr`, if your table has only 14 rows, which can fit on one page? You should consider the `talltblr` environment.
- Overleaf still has installed a quite old version of the `tabularray` package (2021L), which hasn't defined `X`, `Y` and `Z` numbers. For using them, you should ask Overleaf for help, how you can locally load the latest version of the `tabularray` package (2022A).

A MWE composed from corrected your code fragment, which work fine with recent `tabularray` package, and contain some small design changes (font colors, two line column headers, vertical centered column headers, use `S` column for numbers formatting in the second and third columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
{
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
\SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
\SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue2}
\SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}
                    }
\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = fancy,
caption = {Comparison between the difference in the computed electrostatic potential contribution ($\Delta\Psi$) and the difference in experimental relative current ($\Delta V_{0.5}$)},
  label = {tblr:deltavalues},
note{a} = {Both values are in milliVolt.},
note{$\dag$} = {Both computational and experimental data in free-cAMP state.},
remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
                ]{
    width = 0.75\linewidth,
    hlines,
    colspec = {X[l] *{2}{X[c, m, si={table-format=-2.1}]}}, 
    rowhead = 1, 
    rowfoot = 1,
     row{odd} = {bg=gray9}, 
    row{even} = {bg=brown9},
     row{2-5} = {bg=blue, fg=white}, 
       row{Z} = {fg=blue},
                }
Mutations   & {{{Computed\\ $\Delta\Psi$}}} 
                        & {{{Experimental\\ $\Delta V_{0.5}$}}} \\
D244A       &  -6.3     &  -5.9     \\
D244K       & -12.9     &  -6.8     \\
E247A       & -15       & -13.4     \\
E247R       & -34.8     &  -5.7     \\
K464A       &   7       &   8.9     \\
K464E       &  14.4     &  22.8     \\
K472A       &   1.5     &  14.7     \\
K472E       &   3.6     &  19.6     \\
M155A       &   0.4     &   1.9     \\
M155E       &  13.4     &  13.7     \\
M155R       & -15.3     &  -3       \\
Q539A       &   0.3     &  -1.8     \\
R470E       &  16.6     &   0.3     \\
\end{longtblr}
}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: @MaestroGlanz, thank you for editing my answer. After than I observe some more errors in explanation.

Comment: i tried your answer and it gave pretty much the same table - the error still remains, and i already reported the outdated packages to overleaf

but in the meantime, any solution for the spaces between the notes??

Comment: I told you in answer, that you will have problems in Overleaf. Use local installed LaTeX with recent `tabularray` package (instalation will take some hours of works). Or not use `tabularray` package but some less powerful classic package combinations. For example `[table]{xcolor}` and `xltabular`

Comment: @sphero, please **don't edit** my answer! If you have new problem, please ask new question or eventually edit your question.